# Duplicate column Pandas dataframe slice issue

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with duplicate columns: (I need duplicate columns dataframe, which will be passed as a parameter to matplotlib to plot, so the columns' name and content might be same or different)

```
>>> df
                                         PE     RT    Ttl_mkv      PE
STK_ID    RPT_Date                                  
11_STK79  20130115  41.932  2.744   3629.155  41.932
21_STK58  20130115  14.223  0.048  30302.324  14.223
22_STK229 20130115  22.436  0.350  15968.313  22.436
23_STK34  20130115 -63.252  0.663   4168.189 -63.252
```

I can get the second column by : `df[df.columns[1]]`  ,

```
>>> df[df.columns[1]]
STK_ID     RPT_Date
11_STK79   20130115    2.744
21_STK58   20130115    0.048
22_STK229  20130115    0.350
23_STK34   20130115    0.663
```

but if I want to get the first column by `df[df.columns[0]]` , it will give :

```
>>> df[df.columns[0]]
                                   PE      PE
STK_ID    RPT_Date                
11_STK79  20130115  41.932  41.932
21_STK58  20130115  14.223  14.223
22_STK229 20130115  22.436  22.436
23_STK34  20130115 -63.252 -63.252
```

Which one has two columns? That will make my application down for the application just wants the first column but Pandas give 1st & 4th column!  Is it a bug or it is designed as this on purpose ? How to bypass this  issue ?

My pandas version is 0.8.1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really understand why you need to two columns with the same name, avoiding it would probably be the best.

But to answer your question, this would return only 1 of the 'PE' columns:

```
df.T.drop_duplicates().T.PE

STK_ID     RPT_Date
11_STK79   20130115    41.932
21_STK58   20130115    14.223
22_STK229  20130115    22.436
23_STK34   20130115   -63.252
Name: PE
```

or:

```
df.T.ix[0].T
```

Comment: thanks for your tip. But I think "df[df.columns[0]]" return two columns is a design issue . For the syntax tell Pandas very clearly I just want "column[0]" .

Comment: I dissagree. df.columns[0] returns the name of the first column, not the column itself. And you use it with fancy indexing. Therefore i interpret it as 'give me all columns with de name df.columns[0]', so basically df['PE'].

Comment: I see. I should use "df.ix[:,0]" instead of "df[df.columns[0]]"

Comment: I didnt know you could slice it like that with .ix[], nice tip. Yes, for as far as i know that would be a hard reference to the first column only. Its the way to go if your sure that you always need the first, otherwise you might need to search the 'PE' location first with something like "np.where(df.columns == 'PE')"